# How to update the sum of invoices for a project into one of two columns, IS or Business

Tags: c#, .net, sql

What I have is two tables:

One is the invoice table that has a lookup table called `BusinessOrIS` to identify if it is 'IS' or 'Business'; and a spent column that is for the amount the invoice is for.

The other table is the projects table that has two columns that need the update 'totalISSpent' and 'totalBusinessSpent'.

So what I want to do is take the sum of the spent amounts where BusinessOrIS =1(is) and invoice.projectid = the Projects.projectid.  As well as BusinessOrIS =2(Business) and invoice.projectid = the Projects.projectid. And have it roll up to the 'totalISSpent' and 'totalBusinessSpent'

//what i have at this moment is on the c# side of the InsertButton_Click event:

//enter co

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("mystring")SqlTransaction transaction;
db.Open()
transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
UPDATE Projects Set ProjectSpentIS = (SELECT SUM(Invoices.Spent) 
FROM Invoices WHERE Invoices.CostToISorBusiness ='1' 
AND Projects.Projectid = Invoices.ProjectID)

UPDATE Projects Set ProjectSpentBusiness = 
(SELECT SUM(Invoices.Spent) FROM Invoices
    WHERE Invoices.CostToISorBusiness ='2' AND 
    Projects.Projectid = Invoices.ProjectID)
transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: as a bit of advise you may want to wrap your transactional code in a try {} catch{} if there is an error do the rollback in catch part where are you assigning the SqlCommand to execute the Query..? also assign the transaction object to the sql comman object for example sqlcmd.Transaction = transaction; make sure you create sqlcmd as sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();

Comment: are you getting an error or not data?  if it's not updating can you post your table schema and snippet of data?

Comment: Im sorry  i am in between meetings and i will try and post what you ask by tomorrow morning again sorry for the delay! meetings sigh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have issues with your schema design (because you seem to have a multi-domain table, which is a no-no, or at the very least should set your database up for future extensions).  However, you haven't posted enough information to be able to reccommend changes.

However, you should be able to restate your `UPDATE` into one SQL statement:

```
UPDATE Projects as a 
SET ProjectSpentIS = COALESCE((SELECT SUM(b.Spent)
                               FROM Invoices as b
                               WHERE b.CostToISOrBusiness = '1'
                               AND b.ProjectId = a.ProjectId), ProjectSpentIS),
    ProjectSpentBusiness = COALESCE((SELECT SUM(b.Spent)
                                     FROM Invoices as b
                                     WHERE b.CostToISOrBusiness = '2'
                                     AND b.ProjectId = a.ProjectId), 
                                   ProjectSpentBusiness)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT '1'
              FROM Invoices as b
              WHERE b.ProjectId = a.ProjectId
              AND b.CostToISOrBusiness in ('1', '2'))
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry about the no-no!